Cengage Mindtap Error is not accepting submitted SQL Homework into Gradebook. Low Disk Space Popup
I completed the homework with 100%. Tried to submit it and it said it was submitted yet the grade didnt show up in Cengage gradebook for that attempt.
I did a rebuild of the container twice and no change. In the Github Codespaces I see a popup stating:"Low disk space (<5%)- Please free some space to ensure your codespace continues to work correctly." I click on the popup and it doesnt show me how to solve the issue. I tried deleting an entire past chapter's worth of homework but nothing changed. Cengage support didnt help either.
